# Improving rudimentary AI of Angular based chess game

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, chess

I have created a chess game with Angular and chess.js and am trying to improve its rudimentary AI.  The un-improved code currently lives at: https://gist.github.com/dexygen/8a19eba3c58fa6a9d0ff (or https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dexygen/8a19eba3c58fa6a9d0ff/raw/d8ee960cde7d30850c0f00f511619651396f5215/ng-chess)

What the AI currently consists of is checking whether the computer (black) has a move that checkmates (using chess.js' in_checkmate() method), and if so, mating the human (white), otherwise making a random move.  To improve this I thought that instead of merely making a random move, I would have the AI check for white's counters to black's responses.  Then, if White has checkmate, not including those black responses in the moves to randomly select from.

I would like to improve the AI within makeMove() (which currently merely delegates to makeRandomMove()) but I am finding this to be harder than expected.  What I expected to be able to do was, not unlike mateNextMove() (refer to lines 155-168 of the gist), to check for in_checkmate() within a loop, except the loop will be nested to account for black responses *and* white counters to those responses.

Here is my first attempt at what I expected would work but it does not avoid checkmate when possible.

```
function makeMove(responses) {
    var evaluator = new Chess();
    var response;
    var allowsMate;
    var counters = [];
    var candidates = [];

    for (var i=0, n=responses.length; i<n; i++) {
        response = responses[i];
        allowsMate = false;

        evaluator.load(chess.fen());
        evaluator.move(response);
        counters = evaluator.moves();

        //console.log(evaluator.ascii());
        //console.log(counters);

        for (var j=0, k=counters.length; j<k; j++) {
            evaluator.move(counters[j]);
            if (evaluator.in_checkmate()) {
                //console.log('in_checkmate');
                allowsMate = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!allowsMate) {
            candidates.push(response);
        }
    }

    return makeRandomMove(candidates);
}
```

In order to debug/test taking advantage of a little knowledge helps, specifically attempting an early "Scholar's Mate", see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholar%27s_mate.  If Black's random moves make this impractical just start over, the opportunity presents itself as often as not.  Qxf7# is the notation for the mating move of Scholars mate both in the wikipedia article and also as returned by chess.moves().  So I've tried to modify the inner for loop as follows:

```
for (var j=0, k=counters.length; j<k; j++) {
    evaluator.move(counters[j]);
    if (counters[j] == 'Qxf7#') {
        console.log(evaluator.in_checkmate());   
    }
}
```

But I've had this return false and allow me to deliver the mate.  What am I doing wrong (and who possibly wants to help me on this project)?

Comment: Although it's an interesting problem, why would you tag the question with "angularjs"? It has no relevance to Angular whatsoever. (I'm removing the tag)

Comment: World Chess Champion [Mikhail Botvinnik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Botvinnik#Computer_chess) spend decades by trying to fine-tune AI of a chess playing software and World Chess Champion [Garry Kasparov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasparov_Chessmate) spend also significant time by fine-tuning AI of a chess playing software. What I want to say by that is that this question is probably too broad for single Stack Overflow answer and should be directed to a specialized chess software development community. Maybe [Chess (beta) Stack Exchange](http://chess.stackexchange.com) ?

Comment: @xmojmr I disagree that this question doesn't belong.  I'm trying to improve the AI in a very limited and specific way, and I have a programming issue in achieving it.

Comment: Ok, I'm not saying to off-topic-or-close it, neither I'm trying to discourage you and you have my +1, I'm just saying to redirect it, considering your "_who possibly wants to help me on this project_" footnote (connect to an internet chess server so that it can combat other chess engines etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me from the code you posted that you are not undoing the moves you make. When you loop through all possible moves, you make that move, then check for a threat. You should then unmake the move. That is probably why your last test didn't work as well.